# select future dates only django form

Tags: python, django, forms, date

I'm using the `SelectDateWidget` in my form.

Now I want to ensure that the form should only allow future dates, the widget should not set the past dates.
Is there any way that the widget itself should handle it, it should start from tomorrow's date.

forms.py

```
import datetime
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
class HmsDiagnosisForm(ModelForm):
    reconsultation_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `SelectDateWidget` does not support this functionality.

You could try to extend the functionality of the `SelectDateWidget` yourself, but I would suggest using a different widget, for example the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). It does allow you to [restrict the date range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max).

It's pretty straight forward to set up the datepicker widget with Django, and [several  questions about it on stack overflow already](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+datepicker) if you get stuck.

Remember, that restricting the dates on the client side is useful, but it's important to validate the data in your model form on the server side as well.

Comment: thank you..
it was a good suggestion..
i got it working the JQuery Date widget